# Cannot connect to Apple and iTunes Store

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I own an iPhone 4S with IOS 7.1.1 and started to use iCloud 2 days ago. Today, I couldn't connect to iCloud and the iTunes Store. It appears that I need a wi-fi connection to connect, but I've using my wi-fi for some time now without a problem. I can still use Google and What'sapp, but the iPhone is saying I need to have a good connection. I can use other apps that need an internet connection, but every time I open Safari it says that I need to have an internet connection. I even tried some methods to troubleshoot the problem by changing the date and time and rebooting and resetting my phone. Can anyone pls. Help me???

Comment: What happens when you restart the App Store or iTunes Store apps on your iPhone? Just double-press the Home button and end the applications' progress. Then enter back to the respective app and try connecting.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it may be Restrictions which is in:

> Settings -> General -> Restrictions

if this is off, check if everything is turned ON for cellular:

> Settings -> Cellular -> Use cellular data for

If everything is ON, then it could be a type of profile installed for blocking these apps at:

> Settings -> General -> Profiles

Remove what you don't know, let us know if you fixed it.